# Set content type for static resources

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, jsf-2, icefaces-2

I have been trying to find out a way to set content type for static resources within my web application, which are provided as downloadable links. For example I have a .CSV file and when I provide this link on the browser, upon click it's opening in a new window. What I really want is to either 1) download automatically or 2) browser to throw 'Open or Save as' dialog. I'm using Icefaces to render the link but this doesn't matter, I can use plain html with javascript or jquery. Here is my code.

```
<ice:outputLink id="location" value="#{bean.downloadLink}" type="application/x-download" target="_blank">
        <ice:outputText value="Download"/>
</ice:outputLink>
```

Please note that I'm not streaming the file content through http response. If I did that I could have easily set content type and content disposition tags to achieve what I wanted. What I really want is a way to set these headers while rendering static resources as direct links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just provide an URL with a valid extension and register if necessary the extension with a content type by `<mime-mapping>` in `web.xml`.

E.g. the following link which is ultimately produced by JSF regardless of components you use:

```
<a href="file.csv">Download</a>
```

with

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>csv</extension>
    <mime-type>text/csv</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Note that the servlet container has by default already a whole list of mime mappings in its own `web.xml`, among others CSV. Only for example OpenXML Office documents (docx, xlsx, etc) and HTML5 image formats (SVG) may need to be registered manually.

Comment: I've been looking for this since last friday. Thanks, @BalusC!